# Will U-SQL support preprocessor like Local and external parameter(@@)

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Scope support preprocessor LOCAL and external parameter, I found it is very useful, but I couldn't find them in U-SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While U-SQL evolved from SCOPE, there are many language feature differences. One of them is that we removed the preprocessing step that SCOPE had for security reasons (SQL-injection attacks).

U-SQL provides external parameters using the standard parameter/variable naming, e.g., `@parameter`. You can even default an external parameter (and document it in your script) with

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL @parameter = "default";
```

Comment: Do you have example that how PS cmdlet Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob provide value for external variable? couldn't find it online.  Can LocalRunHelper.exe also work with external variable?

Comment: The SDK team is still working on how to expose a parameter model (I asked Matt to add more information once available). Today you would need to write a small wrapper to add the `DECLARE @p = value;` statements to the parameterized script. One tool that exposes a parameter model is Azure Data Factory.